# Best way to add hidden data to cell in datatables.net?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Scenario: I am sending function_name and function_id via AJAX. The function_name is displayed in a column. When a function_name-cell is clicked, I want to to fire off a javascript with the function_id value. What is the best way to achieve this?

A thought I had was to add it to aoColumns as seen below, and make it invisible somehow. But this seems overly complicated, and it would still technically be two different cells. Is there some way to send some hidden parameter data to each cell perhaps?

Big thanks in advance

```
   "aoColumns": [
{ "mDataProp": "function_name" }
{ "mDataProp": "function_id" }
]
```

Comment: I see Jquery has a neat way of storing data: http://api.jquery.com/data/
Perhaps I can use this in conjunction in some clever way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using fnGetData (http://datatables.net/ref). Apparently, the mDataProp is only for values to be **displayed** in the columns, and the other values are still accessible.

```
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function() {

oTable = $('#example').dataTable({...});
$('#example tbody tr').live('click', function () {
        var data = oTable.fnGetData(this);
        alert(data.function_id);
    });

});
```